# Theorem 41.7 in Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, paracompactness

[image]

---

The only part I am having difficulty justifying is why there exists a $W_x \in \{W_\alpha\}$ that intersects only finitely many sets in $\{\mbox{Supp } \psi_\alpha \}$

Comment: I don't think it matters that $W_x$ is an element of the family from the previous paragraph.  Possibly munkres should have picked a different letter

Comment: That’s just the definition of local finiteness.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure. Such an open set must exist by local finiteness, but why must it be a set in $\{W_\alpha\}$, unless Pliny the ill is right and Munkres' isn't actually asserting $W_x \in \{W_\alpha\}$. If $\{W_\alpha\}$ were, say, a basis, then this would be trivially true; but $\{W_\alpha\}$ is just a open cover of $X$.

Comment: $W_x$ is indeed not necessarily a member of the cover.

Comment: Unfortunate notation. It can be that for some $x\in X$ every $W_{\alpha}$ containing $x$ intersects the support of infinitely many $\psi_{\alpha}$. The $W_x$ is meant to be some arbitrary neighbourhood of $x$ that intersects only finitely many $\overline{V_{\alpha}}$, not (necessarily) one of the $W_{\alpha}$. It would have been better to call it $N_x$ or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a subtle point.  Let $W_x$ be one of the sets in the collection $\{W_\alpha\}$ such that $x \in W_x$.  Let $W_\alpha$ be another set in the same collection.  For simplicity of notation, let $S_\alpha$ be the support of $\psi_\alpha$.  The subtlety is that $S_\alpha$ is a closed set: it is the smallest closed set containing the open set $O_\alpha = \psi_\alpha^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$.

We have the following relationships:

$$W_\alpha \subset \overline{W_\alpha} \subset O_\alpha \subset V_\alpha.$$

Suppose that $y \in W_x \cap S_\alpha$.  If $y \in O_\alpha$, then $y \in V_x \cap V_\alpha$.  If $y$ belongs to the frontier (sometimes called the boundary) of $O_\alpha$, then since $W_x$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ it must intersect both $O_\alpha$ (and its complement) and so $W_x \cap O_\alpha \neq \emptyset$; therefore $V_x \cap V_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ in this second case as well.

Since the collection $\{V_\alpha\}$ is locally finite, there can only be finitely many such pairs of indices $x$ and $\alpha$ such that $W_x \cap S_\alpha \neq \emptyset$.